# Find the values of 'a' and 'b'

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$x^4-4x^3+ax^2+4x+b=0$ has two pairs of equal roots. Find the values of $a$ and $b$.

I solved like this. But I was getting a different answer than the original ($a=2, b=1$)

I used relations between roots and coefficients. I was getting a different solution. 
Assumed $p,p,q,q$ as roots.

$2(p+q)=4$  $\Rightarrow$ $(p+q)=2$

$p^2+2pq+q^2=a$ $\Rightarrow$ $(p+q)^2=a$  $\Rightarrow$ $a=4$

$2pq(p+q)=-4$ $\Rightarrow$ $2pq(2)=-4$ $\Rightarrow$ $pq=1$

$(pq)^2=b$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=1$

I was getting $a=4$ and $b=1$

Point me where I made the mistake.

Comment: I used relations between roots and coefficients.
Assumed p,p,q,q as roots.
$2(p+q)=4$;
$p^2+2pq+q^2=a$;
$2pq(p+q)=-4$;
$(pq)^2=b$

I was getting $a=4$ and $b=1$. But I'm not sure whether the answer in  the text book is wrong or my solution. The text book answer is given as $a=2$ and $b=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way. If $x_1, x_2$ are roots, then let $(x-x_1)(x-x_2) = x^2 +  cx + d$, and we obtain

\begin{align} 
x^4 - 4x^3 + ax^2 + 4x + b 
&= (x^2 + cx + d)^2 \\
&= x^4 + 2cx^3 + (c^2+2d)x^2 + 2cdx + d^2 
\end{align}

It follows that 
\begin{cases}
2c = -4 \\
2cd = 4 \\
a = c^2 + 2d \\
b = d^2
\end{cases}

$\implies c = -2, \ d = -1, \ a = 2, \ b = 1 $

---

Note that the roots of $x^2-2x-1$ are $1 \pm \sqrt{2}$, which are irrational, so working with them is much more cumbersome.

**Edit:** Using Vieta's formulas we obtain

\begin{cases}
2p + 2q = 4 \\
p^2 + 4pq + q^2 = a \\
2p^2q + 2pq^2 = -4 \\
p^2q^2 = b 
\end{cases}

$\implies p+q=2, pq=-1$

$\implies a = (p+q)^2 + 2pq = 2, \ b = (pq)^2 = 1$

Comment: Awesome. Nice Work there. Can you please check my solution and tell me where I have gone wrong?

I used relations between roots and coefficients.
Assumed p,p,q,q as roots.
$2(p+q)=4$  gives $(p+q)=2$


$p^2+2pq+q^2=a$; 

$(p+q)^2=a$;

$a=4$


$2pq(p+q)=-4$;


$(pq)^2=b$<br/>


I was getting $a=4$ and $b=1$.

Comment: See my edit. Your equation for $a$ is wrong. Note that there 6 possible pairs you can pick from 4 roots, since ${4 \choose 2} = 6$. Two of them are $(p,p)$ and $(q,q)$, so the other 4 must be $(p,q)$

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: write $$x^4-4x^3+ax^2+4x+b$$ in the form $$(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)^2$$
Then you will get
$$x^4+x^2(-2\alpha-2\beta)+x^2(\alpha^2+4\alpha\beta+\beta^2)+x(-2\alpha^2\beta-2\alpha\beta^2)+\alpha^2\beta^2$$

Comment: I used relations between roots and coefficients.
Assumed $p,p,q,q$ as roots.
$2(p+q)=4$;

$p^2+2pq+q^2=a$;

$2pq(p+q)=-4$;

$(pq)^2=b$

I was getting $a=4$ and $b=1$. But I'm not sure whether the answer in  the text book is wrong or my solution. The text book answer is given as $a=2$ and $b=1$

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy exercise to see that given a polynomial $P $, then $P $ has a multiple root at $x_0$ iff $(x-x_0)|P,P'$. In your case, you see that $\gcd (P,P') $ must be of degree 2, and I think this will solve the problem.